# What is the type of composition of two functions -- for example (flip . const)

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, ghci, strong-typing

I've started learning Haskell and I'm curious how to find out the type of composition of functions: for example:

```
:t flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c

:t const
const :: a -> b -> a
```

how manually do `:t (flip . const)`?

of course GHCi can help you with that:

```
:t (flip.const)
(flip . const) :: (b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

but how to do it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are three functions here into play:

1. [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-46-);
2. [**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip); and
3. [**`const :: a -> b -> a`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=const).

Note that if you use the `(.)` function as an operator, you actually have written:

```
(.) flip const
```

or more verbose:

```
((.) flip) const
```

now let us first write the signatures of the functions in a verbose way, and with different vaiable names, such that these do not clash:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
flip :: (d -> (e -> f)) -> (e -> (d -> f))
const :: g -> (h -> g)
```

So we apply `(.)` to `flip`, that thus means that we have to match the parameter of `(.)` which has type `(b -> c)` with the signature of flip, so we resolve this with:

```
b               -> c
(d -> (e -> f)) -> (e -> (d -> f))
```

Which is the only match possible (notice the brackets). So that means that:

```
b ~ (d -> (e -> f))
c ~ (e -> (d -> f))
```

(here `a ~ b` means that `a` and `b` are the same type)

As a result, the type of `(.) flip` is

```
(.) flip :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

Which is again a function with one parameter (all functions in Haskell have one parameter), and that parameter has type `a -> b`.
and we apply that function to `const`, so we do again a pattern matching:

```
a -> b
g -> (h -> g)
```

so that means that `a ~ g` and `b ~ (d -> (e -> f)) ~ (h -> g)`, as a result we know that `d ~ h` and `g ~ (e -> f)`.

We know that the type of `((.) flip) const` has type:

```
((.) flip) const :: a -> c`
```

So now it is a matter of substituting: `a` for `g` and `g ~ (e -> f)`, so `a ~ (e -> f)`. Furthermore we know that `c ~ (e -> (d -> f))`, so that means that the type is:

```
((.) flip) const :: (e -> f) -> (e -> (d -> f))
```

or in less verbose form:

```
flip . const :: (e -> f) -> e -> d -> f
```

which is, except for variable renaming, the same as the type derived by GHCi.

Answer (score 2):

We have also `(>>>) = flip (.)` which can be easier to deal with, type-wise:

```
f . g = g >>> f

g ::       a -> b
f ::            b -> c
g >>> f :: a ->      c
```

thus

```
flip . const = const >>> flip

const :: a1 -> (b1 ->     a1    )
flip ::        (a2 -> (b2 -> c2)) -> (b2 -> a2 -> c2)
const >>> flip 
     ::  a1 ->                        b2 -> a2 -> c2      -- where
--           b1 ~ a2,   a1 ~ b2 -> c2
     ::  (b2 -> c2) ->                b2 -> a2 -> c2
```

Or `flip . const :: (b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`. GHCi says the same.

From this type we immediately see that `(flip . const) f x z = f x`. Indeed `(flip . const) f x z = flip (const f) x z = const f z x = f x`.

Three lessons to take away from this:

- types associate to the right, as functional application associates to the left, `f x y z = (((f x) y) z)`, `f :: a -> (b -> (c -> d))`;
- vertically aligning the stuff helps;
- numbering the type vars in separate types helps keep them apart.